# RingBufferLogEvent Size in Heapdump

Tags: jvm, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I was getting heap overflow exception. When I inspected from the heap dump file, I can see that following object is taking the most space:

> org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.RingBufferLogEvent    524,288
>   (8.7%)    83,886,080 B (22.4%)    105,903,740 B (28.3%)

What does it mean? Is logging taking the memory size? If so, how can I fix it?